# Rotate button settings and values on each click, repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display a button, starting with "unmarked". As the user clicks the button, I need it to change to the next button, "form". When each of these clicks happen, I would like a post request made through ajax to update the value in the database associated with the ID of the button. This ID comes from the database where other information is being shown next to the button. I believe that part is done with an onclick=functionname(123456) event? When the user reaches the end (completed), another click simply starts it over at unmarked.

I've been searching stackoverflow for hours however have not been able to find anything related to what I am trying to do and very new to jquery/ajax/javascript

```
<button type="button" name="Unmarked" value="0" class="btn btn-default"/>Unmarked</button>
<button type="button" name="Form" value="1" class="btn btn-info"/>Form</button>
<button type="button" name="Frame" value="2" class="btn btn-primary"/>Frame</button>
<button type="button" name="S/NB" value="3" class="btn btn-warning"/>S/NB</button>
<button type="button" name="S/B" value="4" class="btn btn-danger"/>S/B</button>
<button type="button" name="Completed" value="5" class="btn btn-success"/>Completed</button>
```

I'm hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Would it make sense to hide all buttons but the current active one, then on each click change css of the clicked button to hidden, and the now active button to visible?

Comment: Sounds like it would work for what I want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment...

We have an array of the item id's that you want to iterate through.

```
var buttonArray = ["unmarked", "form", "frame", "snb", "sb", "completed"];
```

We keep track of which items is currently visible

```
var currentItemIndex = 0;
```

Finally we will call the function to change visibility on every button click.

```
function changeButtonVisibility() {
  var buttonClicked = $("#" + buttonArray[currentItemIndex]);
  var nextItemIndex = 0;

  if(currentItemIndex + 1 > buttonArray.length - 1) {
    nextItemIndex = 0;
  } else {
    nextItemIndex = currentItemIndex + 1;
  }

  var nextButton = $("#" + buttonArray[nextItemIndex]);
  currentItemIndex = nextItemIndex;

  buttonClicked.addClass("hidden");
  nextButton.removeClass("hidden");
}
```

Essentially you take the current button, add the class hidden, take the next button, remove the class hidden. The if statement ensures that if you hit the last item, you start over again with the first item.

Lastly, bind the function as a click event to your buttons.

```
 $("#unmarked").click(function() {
  changeButtonVisibility();
});

$("#form").click(function() {
...
```

Depending on your specific use case, you could probably come up with a more elegant way to solve this. Also you can definitely eliminate some lines of code. However, I hope the example gives you a good starting point or idea on how to tackle the problem.

Working example: [jsbin.com/xeyejesaxe](http://jsbin.com/xeyejesaxe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work like I need. The buttons are output through a while loop and therefore only the first in the list work.